# How to use to_char function in JPA to get records from a timestamp

Tags: java, postgresql, jpa

I am try to query from and database using eclipse link using entities. when I use normal query records are returned from current date by when I use `JPA` zero records are returned. Where could I be doing wrong, Or how can I use to_char function in `JPA` my database is postgresql.
normal sql query that returns records

```
select * 
from mytable 
where  to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD') = '2016-01-19';
```

MyEntity

```
@Temporal(javax.persistence.TemporalType.DATE)
 private Date transaction_date;
  EntityManager e = EntityMgr.MyFact().createEntityManager();
        e.getTransaction().begin();
 Query qry = e.createQuery("from MyEntity u where  u.transaction_date=?1");
  qry.setParameter(1, new Date(), TemporalType.DATE);
```

Comment: What type is your database field `transaction_date`?

Comment: @thomas the datatype is timestamp

Comment: where is your Entity? You have omitted "SELECT u" from your JPQL (incorrectly).

Comment: Have you tried using CriteriaBuilder?

Comment: @NeilStockton have tried that also and doe not work

Comment: @hasnae do you have that code. I havent tried

Comment: @NeilStockton records is still zero after adding the select u

Comment: So DEBUG it FFS. Look at the SQL invoked. If you won't post your Entity then you are on your own

Comment: @NeilStockton What log do you want to see?

Comment: I don't want to see any log, __you__ do. It has the SQL invoked for that JPQL query in it. I _wanted_ to see the Entity but you don't want to show it

Comment: @NeilStockton here is the log SELECT amount ,id, TRANSACTION_DATE FROM PAYMENT WHERE (TRANSACTION_DATE = ?)
 bind => [2016-01-18]

Comment: CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
CriteriaQuery criteriaQuery = criteriaBuilder.createQuery();
Root<MyEntity> MyEntity = criteriaQuery.from(entityManager.getMetamodel().entity(MyEntity.class));
criteriaBuilder.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, root.get("transactionDate"));
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQuery)
List<MyEntity> = query.getResultList();

Comment: Side note: don't use `to_char()` for this at all. You bind a `date` type, compare it with another date, like `DATE(u.transaction_date)=?1` or `CAST(u.transaction_date AS DATE)=?1`. What JPA implementation are you using? (F.ex. these above should work in hibernate.)

Comment: @hasnae how do I pass the current date from above code

Comment: @Pozs I am using eclipse link

Comment: You should be able to use [`CAST` in eclipselink](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/UserGuide/JPA/Basic_JPA_Development/Querying/JPQL#Functions), like this: `CAST(u.transaction_date DATE)=?1` or `SQL('CAST(? AS DATE)', u.transaction_date)=?1`

Comment: criteriaBuilder.equal(criteriaBuilder.function("TO_CHAR", String.class, root.get("transactionDate")), new date());

Comment: @hasnae thanks alot my problem is now solved

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with  qry.setParameter(1, new Date(), TemporalType.TIMESTAMP);

Comment: Could you please turn your logger on so we can view the SQL that is being sent to the database

<property name="eclipselink.logging.file" value="output.log"/>

Comment: I guess you can use the function() API to call a database function, such as "TO_CHAR".

https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/Criteria#Special_Operations

Comment: Pandey here is the output SELECT amount ,id, TRANSACTION_DATE FROM PAYMENT WHERE (TRANSACTION_DATE = ?)
 bind => [2016-01-18]

Comment: how can I use that function ?similar to the query in my question?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_char` function using `operator`

like

```
OPERATOR('ToChar', transaction_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')= '2016-01-19';
```